# StereoBM in OpenCV 2.4.3 giving non-deterministic results

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am using StereoBM to compute the stereo disparity map using OpenCV 2.4.3, and I seem to be getting different disparity maps every time I run. Not visually noticeable, but several pixels are different, in random.

I tried saving the disparity map to a YML file, and upon comparing them using WinMerge, I notice that several pixels have a value of -16 where the other run produced a disparity value. This is easily reproducible also.

This snippet shows what I am doing:

`//initialize bm

StereoBM bm(StereoBM::BASIC_PRESET, 128, 7); 
bm.state->preFilterType = CV_STEREO_BM_XSOBEL;

bm.state->preFilterCap = 63;

bm.state->SADWindowSize = 7;

bm.state->minDisparity = 0;

bm.state->numberOfDisparities = 96;

bm.state->textureThreshold = 3;

bm.state->uniquenessRatio = 3;

bm.state->speckleWindowSize = 20;

bm.state->speckleRange = 32;

bm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;`

`// Get rectified images

videoOut[MASTER] = Mat(frameHeight, frameWidth, CV_8UC3, static_cast(frameBuf[MASTER]));

videoOut[SLAVE]  = Mat(frameHeight, frameWidth, CV_8UC3, static_cast(frameBuf[SLAVE]));`

`// grayscale conversion

cvtColor(videoOut[MASTER], frame[MASTER], CV_RGB2GRAY);

cvtColor(videoOut[SLAVE], frame[SLAVE], CV_RGB2GRAY);`

`// Subsample

            resize(frame[MASTER], frame[MASTER], cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

            resize(frame[SLAVE], frame[SLAVE], cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, cv::INTER_LINEAR);`

`// stereo computation

Mat disp = cv::Mat(frame[MASTER].rows, frame[MASTER].cols, CV_16S);

bm(frame[MASTER], frame[SLAVE], disp);`

`// write to file

FileStorage f1;

f1.open("data.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

f1 << "disp" << disp;`

Is this a bug in OpenCV or am I doing something wrong?
I tried writing out the input images also, and they are identical everytime. It is only the disparity map that is changing.

Comment: encountering same problem